# Advice: where to situate html table content: in JS or HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, dhtml

SHORT: my python code generates a webpage with a table.  i'm considering rewriting it to generate a js file instead, that holds the table contents in an array ... and then let the table be generated client-side. I am not sure of the pros and cons.  Anyone care to offer their experience/insight?  Are there other solutions?

LONG: the web page contains a single table and an embedded gmap.  the table is a set of locations with several columns of location-stats and also two navigation columns.  one nav column consists of onclicks that will recenter embedded gmap to the lat,lon of the location.  the other nav column consists of hrefs that open a new window with a gmap centered on the lat,lon.

Until recently, my python code would do some number crunching on a list of files, and then generate the html file. also i wrote a js file that keeps the webpage liquid upon browser window resizing.

Recently, I modified my python code so that it:

1. placed the lat,lon info in a custom attribute of the tr elements
2. no longer produced the nav column tds

and then wrote a js function that

1. loops through the trs onLoad
2. reads the lat,lon from the custom attribute
3. inserts the nav tds

fwiw, this reduced the size of the html file by 70% while increasing the js by 10%.

ok, so now I am debating if I should go all the way and write my python code to generate 2 files

1. an essentially abstract html file
2. a js file containing a js array of the locations and their stats

Comment: If you have the time, I would try it - this is how a lot of pages are made today, and it puts most of the burden on the client, so that if your webpage ever gets horribly popular, it's less work for the server. However, I don't have anything to concretely back this up, and if you're strapped for time, don't fix what isn't broken.

Comment: thanks Gail, I might give it a try ... maybe incorporating the suggestion below of using JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your API can output a JSON document with your data, you gain significant flexibility and future-proofing.  This might even be something your users will want to access directly for their own external consumption.  And of course your JS code can easily generate a table from this data.

However nobody here can tell you whether this is worth doing or not, as that depends entirely on the scope of your project and opportunity cost of time spent re-architecting.

Comment: I would recommend outputting json if you can instead of outputting a js file that contains an array. The json file will guarantee you much more flexibility in the future.

Comment: thanks, it sounds like something I ought to learn, i'm reading about JSON now on wiki.  I have to say though at first glance i'm a bit turned off by its hairyness: the file size would be about twice that of an old fashion CSV. What do you think?

Comment: actually scratch that, the wiki example shows only an object .... the json.org page explains that there are also arrays.  great suggestion! thank you!